# Conditional folding on VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

So let me explain what I'm trying to do since the post title does not make enough sense I guess. Let's say I have the following markdown format file opening on VSCode,

```
# my schedule today 2/2

today I'm going to ...
here is very long hundreds of lines text ...

# my schedule today 2/3

just like the above "#" block...

# my very important schedule for 2/4

this must be very important...

# my schedule today 2/5

same...

--- 

and more hundreds of "#" blocks continues...
```

Now if you do "Fold Level 1" command on the file on VSCode, you will simply get something below you know?

```
# my schedule today 2/2
# my schedule today 2/3
# my very important schedule for 2/4
# my schedule today 2/5
```

But here I'd like to obtain something like below. Basically fold all blocks with an exception `/.*important.*/`.

```
# my schedule today 2/2
# my schedule today 2/3
# my very important schedule for 2/4

this must be very important...

# my schedule today 2/5
```

So, is/how can I do this?

Comment: Hello Mr close voter. Tell us how we can improve this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In a Text cell or a .md file, at least, you can use HTML like this in the Markdown:

```
<details>
<summary> <b>My Schedule Today 2/2</summary>
<li>Do this</li>
<li>Then Do that</li>
</details>
</p>
```

the key bits are the `<details`> and `<summary`> tags.

More here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#diagrams-and-flowcharts